# Rails has many through fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form I would like to create that populates the corresponding model form for, and a fields_for that populates a has many through table.

The **plan.rb** model:

```
class Plan < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :plan_materials
  has_many :materials, through: :plan_materials
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :materials
end
```

The **materials.rb** model:

```
class Material < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :plan_materials
  has_many :plans, through: :plan_materials
end
```

And the **PlanMaterial** model:

```
class PlanMaterial < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :plan
  belongs_to :material
end
```

This is what I have in the plan form:

```
<%= form_for @plan do |form| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= form.label :description %>
    <%= form.text_field :description, class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <%= form.fields_for :materials, plan.materials.build do |material_fields| %>
    <%= material_fields.text_field :title %>
  <% end %>

  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I have created fields_for forms before but never trying to input the information for the form being created, and the id of the material they are selecting, in a new table from that same form.

I am creating this through a `plan.materials.build` which I realize could possibly be the wrong way to go about doing this because I don't think it would be building that in the `plan_materials` table.

```
class PlansController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @plans = Plan.all
  end

  def new
    @plan = Plan.new
    @plan.materials.build
  end

  def create
    @plan = Plan.new(plan_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @plan.save
        format.html { redirect_to plan_path, notice: 'Plan has been created' }
      else
        format.html { render :new, notice: 'There was an error saving your plan' }
      end
    end
  end

  private

  def plan_params
    params.require(:plan).permit(:name, :description, :grade_id, :subject_id, :unit_id, materials_attributes: [:title])
  end
end
```

So, just to recap, I would like to create a plan, and be able to add materials to that plan. I need to have that plan created in the plans table, along with the id of the plan that was created and the id of the material that was added in that form. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Try to remove `plan.materials.build` from the form. What do you have in logs for create action?